# MATLAB - stretching histogram algorithm

Tags: matlab

I need to stretch histogram of two images, but using my own algorithm. This is my current code:

```
img_gray = imread('hist_gray.jpg');
img_couple = imread('hist_couple.bmp');

img_gray_mod = rozciaganie(img_gray);
img_couple_mod = rozciaganie(img_couple);

subplot(4,2,1);
imshow(img_gray);
title("Obraz oryginalny");

subplot(4,2,2);
imhist(img_gray);
title("Histogram");

subplot(4,2,3);
imshow(img_gray_mod);
title("Obraz po modyfikacji");

subplot(4,2,4);
imhist(img_gray_mod);
title("Histogram");

subplot(4,2,5);
imshow(img_couple);
title("Obraz oryginalny");

subplot(4,2,6);
imhist(img_couple);
title("Histogram");

subplot(4,2,7);
imshow(img_couple_mod);
title("Obraz po modyfikacji");

subplot(4,2,8);
imhist(img_couple_mod);
title("Histogram");

function r = rozciaganie(img);
mn = min(min(img));
mx = max(max(img));
r = 255*((img-mn)/(mx-mn));
end
```

That's what I get as output images and their histograms. Can anyone help me with this?

[image: result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that your image is of type `uint8`. The following line:

```matlab
r = 255*((img-mn)/(mx-mn));
```

does computations using 8-bit integers. `img-mn` should be fine, but then you divide by `mx-mn`, causing all your pixels to be either 0 or 1 (any non-integer value is rounded down). Finally, multiplying by 255 leads to values of 0 or 255 for all your pixels.

The simplest solution is to perform the operations using floating-point operations:

```matlab
function r = rozciaganie(img);
img = double(img); % convert to double so all arithmetic is floating-point arithmetic
mn = min(img(:));  % better than min(min(img))
mx = max(img(:));
r = 255*((img-mn)/(mx-mn));
r = uint8(r); % convert back to uint8 so the display works as expected
end
```

Simply reordering the integer arithmetic doesn't work as expected either, for example `(255*(img-mn))/(mx-mn)` overflows values in the multiplication, results larger than 255 all become 255. The division after that will not recover those values. `(img-mn)*(255/double(mx-mn))` is the best approximation, but might lead to some rounding artifacts. You could try it, though, to see if the results are good enough.

Comment: I don't know why, but results are still the same

Comment: @inLwetrust: Are you sure it's the right `rozciaganie` function that is being called? The above works for me.